Emulating Docker on Kubernetes cluster
I've got a very little experience with Kubernetes, but I have a good one with Docker and I'd like to have the same behaviour with both two environments. Let's take an example with this docker compose file:
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8080:80

  curl:
    container_name: curl
    image: curlimages/curl
    command:
      - curl
      - http://nginx
    depends_on:
      - nginx

With this file, container curl is able to interact with container nginx with its internal port (80) and the output confirms (I've command docker logs curl):
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
100   615  100   615    0     0  1016k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  600k

But port 80 of the container nginx is exposed to the host via port 8080 and in fact if I run on my computer the command curl http://127.0.0.1:8080, the output confirms the service is accessible:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>

Transposing this to Kubernetes, the best choice should be create a Deployment this way:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:stable-alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
      restartPolicy: Always

But I've got some a problem with the service, I created this one:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: proxy
  labels:
    app: proxy
spec:
  selector:
    app: proxy
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer

With this service pods can interact with nginx via port 80 but the same port is exposed to the host. Is there a way to emulate the same behaviour of docker compose? Should NodePort + Ingress be a good solution?
Thanks in advance to every one.

Kubernetes is designed as a multiple-node clustered environment.  Which node is "the host" for purposes of calling into the application?  What is provisioning the load balancer?  There might be implementation-specific annotations on the Service that can control this.

Sorry, my fault. I'm using K3S

In your concrete case, you've deployed ngnix using your deployment, and afterward, you can create imperatively a service (in the same namespace) i.e.
# creating service proxy in the default namespace
kubectl expose deployment nginx --name=proxy --type="LoadBalancer" --port=80 --target-port=80

Where --port flag is the one you're going to expose it on your localhost and --target-port is the one on which the container is listening.

If you want to serialize your service to yaml just run kubectl get svc proxy -oyaml and save it to disk.
As you probably figured out, services are of multiple types e.g. ClusterIP (default), NodePort, LoadBalancer. The discussion is highly dependent on your k8s setup (if is a manged cluster then most often cloud providers support external load balancers)

Hi, thanks for your answer. This solves just a part of my problem: pods can interact via port 80, and that's. But also I'd like to expose port 8080 the host. Schematically this is my objective:
Pods binding: 80->80
Host/pod binding 8080->80
Is it possible to reach?
